# Photoswipe reply/info pane

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I'm using http://photoswipe.com for my picture gallery.

Now i would like to implement a reply/info bar/pane like they have here. 
http://www.fotosidan.se/gallery/viewpiclarge/356031/3549694.htm?_p=3549689

But i don't know how to create the element in the code so that it pushes away the image in stead of creating an overlay.

Comment: Can you show the code ?

Comment: @Anoopsaju I created a new div using Firefox Inspector and tried different css settings, so i don't have any other code then the default photoswipe.